# How to remove the lines which appear on file 1 from another file 2 KEEPING empty lines?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, match, line

I know that in other questions you solve the first part of "How to remove the lines which appear on file 1 from another file 2" with:
`comm -23 file1 file2` and `grep -Fvxf file1 file2`

But in my case I have empty lines separating data sets that I need to keep, for example:

File 1:

```
A
B
C

D
E
F

G
H
I
```

File 2

```
A

D
F

I
```

what I want as a result:

```
B
C

E
    
G
H
```

The solution can be in bash or csh.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have empty lines in `File 2` (the file of lines to be removed from `File 1`) if you don't want empty lines removed from `File 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` please try following once.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} !NF || !($0 in arr)' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                  ##Mentioning awk program from here.
FNR==NR{               ##Checking if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  arr[$0]              ##Creating array with index of $2 here.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(!NF || !($0 in arr))  ##If line is empty OR not in arr then print it.
' file2 file1          ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```